# PHP script inside of string?

Tags: php

Is this possible?

What I am trying to accomplish:

- Create a html template in the form of a string
- Inside the string, add a script, something like `include 'php/countries.php';`
- Echo entire string to html page

Everything but the 2nd step works. I would like to see a php file echo the question being asked, onto the html page, including an echo from another php file.

**EXAMPLE**

```
echo "<div id=\"first\"><?php include \'countries.php\'; ?></div>";
```

I have tried the above, as well as the below:

**EXAMPLE**

```
echo "<div id=\"first\">".include 'countries.php'."</div>";
```

Would this require eval?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: The include function returns a boolean not a string. You should create a countries() function that returns the information you're looking for and just call the function accordingly.

Comment: `echo "<div id=\"first\">"; include 'countries.php'; echo "</div>";`

Comment: @rosscowar I always mix up require and include.. thanks

Comment: @Mike So this works perfectly. However, is there any hidden issues to breaking up the echos like this?

Comment: @Ricky No, there isn't. It just goes from one statement to 3 separate statements.

Answer (score 2):

Seems a bit silly, but you could do the following:

```
echo "<div id=\"first\">" . file_get_contents('countries.php') . "</div>";
```

Or...

```
echo "<div id=\"first\">";
include "countries.php";
echo "</div>";
```

Or...

```
$externalfile = compileexternal('countries.php');
function compileexternal($file) {
    ob_start();
    require $file;
    return ob_get_clean();
}

echo "<div id=\"first\">" . $externalfile . "</div>";
```

If none of these are what you need, please update the question. There are a dozen ways.

Comment: That's probably *not* what is wanted considering countries.php is a PHP file and could contain server-side code.

Comment: I do like this method, although @Mike was right, countries.php DOES contain more code.

Comment: @Ricky See my comment in your question then.

Comment: Thanks for the third option. I've never seen this used. Will be looking into this!

Comment: Does ob_end_clean(); automatically happen once the scope of the function is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
eval()
```

But it is not a good practice.

Comment: Not to extend this conversation, but I actually do use eval in one particular case. It's better not to use it but if you need to, just separate it from user input.

Comment: @Mike you are probably confusing it with exec() or system().
http://php.net/manual/bg/function.eval.php
http://bg2.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
eval parses a string just as an included/required filed gets parsed.
It is not a good practice(unlike require/include) because a string variable can hold anything (deppends really, but you know)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

For example, your string could be;

```
<div id="first">{{countries.php}}</div>
```

You'd then do;

```
$string = "<div id='first'>{{test2.php}}</div>";

echo preg_replace_callback("/(\{\{.+\}\})/", function($matches) {
   include_once( str_replace(array("{", "}"), "", $matches[0]));
}, $string);
```

- Check the file exists `if( file_exists() )`
- Check the file can be included (we don't want to include `../../../../../etc/passwd`